# .NET 6 OracleManagedDataAccessClient behaves strange

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, oracle-manageddataaccess, oracle.manageddataaccess

I have an application which is .NET 6 MVC application. I am reading an excel file, preparing INSERT statements and executing them. I am debugging the code everything works fine i am doing inserts and i am commiting a serializable transaction. No exception occurs and i see the data at the table.
But even though all of this i see an error message -> "**Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleExceptionXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX**"
This is the message only. There no exception no event log nothing.
Oracle Managed Data Access version -> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core (3.21.90)

I am publishing the web site on IIS 10. (10.0.17763.1)

How can i clear this exception?

Comment: Without more details (for example a relevant part of the code where the exception is thrown - I know, hard without a stacktrace) this is close to impossible to answer. Also, it is *very* unlikely that the oracle client sources actually raise an exception by _that_ name (or message). So most likely there is some custom code involved that issues it that way (all the `X`s). Try searching your code base and possibly dependencies for that.

Comment: @Christian.K I solved the problem within upgrading the dll. The dll version is now 3.21.100. I was facing this issue at 3.21.80 version. After upgrade to 3.21.90 i faced the issue again and asked here. After asked here and thanks for your answer i upgraded from 3.21.90 to 3.21.100 and my problem is resolved. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem within upgrading the dll from version **3.21.90** to **3.21.100**. First i faced this issue at **3.21.80**. After i upgraded the dll from **3.21.80** to **3.21.90**. I faced the same issue again so i asked here. After @Christian.K's answer i upgraded the dll from **3.21.90** to **3.21.100** and my problem is resolved. Thank you.